# How to handle youtube deleted videos using youtube api from json request

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, youtube-api, jsonresult, youtube-channels

I want to get youtube videos from youtube api using json request. Now i get videos from youtube using json. Example the url have some deleted videos (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlOHWLqgcoY&list=PLD62D6701B15FD3E1) but i get only playing videos not deleted videos. Is it possible or any other way to handle youtube deleted videos using json results.

This is my code to get youtube videos

```
string getPlaylistVideoUrl = https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLD62D6701B15FD3E1?v=2&safeSearch=strict&orderby=position&start-index=1&max-results=25&alt=json;
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getPlaylistVideoUrl);
using (WebResponse response=await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
using (Stream responseStream=response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
   var jsonResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
   var videosList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YouTubeVideosByPlaylist>(jsonResult);
   if (videosList.Feed != null)
   {
      if (videosList.Feed.Entry != null)
      {
           //Add entries to class
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve the youtube deleted videos problem. if you get the playlist to given **format=6** in the youtube api Url.

```
string getPlaylistVideoUrl = https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLD62D6701B15FD3E1?v=2&safeSearch=strict&orderby=position&start-index=1&max-results=25&alt=json&format=6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Videos that are not playable will normally have `app$control` elements set in their JSON response when retrieved using v2 of the Data API. Here's an example of what to look for in your response JSON:

```
"app$control": {
 "app$draft": {
  "$t": "yes"
 },
 "yt$state": {
  "$t": "This video is not available in your region.",
  "name": "restricted",
  "reasonCode": "requesterRegion"
 }
}
```

There are [other reasons](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html) why a video might not be playable in a given playback scenario, so the absence of `app$control` doesn't ensure that the video can always be played. But if `app$control` **is** there, then the video can't be played.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google documentation "If a video is not playable, the entry for that video will not contain a <media:content> tag. In addition, the entry may contain an <app:control> tag that contains an explanation of why the video is not playable"

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_testing