# Replace YouTube Error Thumbnail with My Own

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a unique challenge.  We have lists of YouTube videos that members have posted and they are shown on a page that shows all the thumbnails.  However, sometimes these videos become unavailable or deleted and the thumbnail changes to a grey box with 3 dots.  How can I replace this image, with an image of my own making.

Here is an example: http://www.storeboard.com/videos/music/ look for the video entitled "The Six Teens", it is showing with the greyed out image and three dots.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the picture there is a prefix #at=24

http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/vkAusm1SM7I#at=24/hqdefault.jpg

http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/vkAusm1SM7I/hqdefault.jpg

When fetching with the gdata API just detect if #at=24 is availible and then replace the thumb.

Comment: This doesn't work.. Look: http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Auwgk94fwTc/hqdefault.jpg any other suggestions

Comment: Have you looked here then for the gdata solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170814/how-to-handle-youtube-deleted-videos-using-youtube-api-from-json-request